# Why do I get error message trying to crossvalidate PCR using matlab?

Tags: matlab, error-handling, regression, evaluation

I am using the commands proposed [here](http://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/partial-least-squares-regression-and-principal-components-regression.html). When I execute

```
PCRmsep = sum(crossval(@pcrsse,X,Y,'KFold',6),1) / n;
```

I get the following error messages:

> Error using crossval>evalFun (line 480)
>   The function 'pcrsse' generated the following error:
>   Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
>
> Error in crossval>getFuncVal (line 497) funResult =
>   evalFun(funorStr,arg(:));
>
> Error in crossval (line 343)
>       funResult = getFuncVal(1, nData, cvp, data, funorStr, []);

What does this error mean and how can I prevent this error?

> X: 24x9 matrix
>
> Y: 24x1 matrix

Comment: put a breakpoint in pcrsse function and you'll find out how and where it crashes.

Comment: `dbstop if error` better @giosans

Comment: The use of `dbstop` is implicitly suggesting the use of breakpoints. There's no doubt the error is in `pcrsse`. @Andre Biguri,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to Matlab and also trying to use this function. I was getting the same error and had a look at the function. For me, saving a copy and changing the maxNumComp value from 10 to 8 (I have 8 predictors) made it work. Yet to figure out why...